# What CPUs use a skewed associative cache?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, computer-architecture, cache

What CPUs use a [skewed associative cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Two-way_skewed_associative_cache)?

I see several people imply that, with roughly the same hardware, a skewed-associative cache often has better performance than a traditional set-associative cache. [(a)](http://opencores.org/forum,OpenRISC,0,1763) [(b)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/Cache#2_way_skewed_associative)

Ideally I'd like to find a soft-core processor in VHDL or Verilog that uses a skewed associative cache -- haven't found one yet, but perhaps I'm not searching in the right places with the right keywords.
Details about a skewed associative cache in a mass-production hardwired CPUs I would also find interesting.

Comment: A few years ago I found an obscure soft core that indicated that skewed associativity was an option, but I doubt I can find that again (assuming such is even still available). Perhaps the closest for mass produced processors might be an old PA-RISC that used a single non-modulo-power-of-two hash for indexing its huge L1 caches, but this was **not** skewed. (It's flattering that the Open Cores link was to a post I made!) You might find [this article](https://sites.google.com/site/paulclaytonplace/andy-glew-s-comparch-wiki/skewed-associativity) from Andy Glew's CompArch wiki interesting.

Comment: Sun's Rock had a "32-entry, two-way skewed-associative way-predicted micro data translation look-aside buffer" ("Rock: A High Performance Sparc CMT Processor", Shailender Chaudhry et al., 2009), but that chip never made it to market.